# How to push or append a Option[Long] to Seq[Long] if the option is defined?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use the code below to append items into a `Seq`, I realize in scala that a `Seq` may be immutable, so this might not work as I expect.

```scala
object Main extends App {
  val x: Long = 122222222
  val y: Option[Long] = Some(133333333)
  // val y: Option[Long] = None
  val z: Option[Long] = Some(144444444)

  val users: Seq[Long] = Seq(x)

  if (y.isDefined) users.appended(y)
  if (z.isDefined) users.appended(z)
  
  println(users)
  println(users.length)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my key learnings on this:

1. keep things functional (append is not really)
2. have a seq of both long / option log if you need it
3. map over the seq to turn everything option using match case
4. filter out all empty option values (none values)
5. now that we're sure were not gonna throw just use .get on the options

```
object Main extends App {
  val x: Long = 122222222
  val y: Option[Long] = Some(133333333)
  // val y: Option[Long] = None
  val z: Option[Long] = Some(144444444)

  val users: Seq[Long | Option[Long]] = Seq(x, y, x, None)

  val cleanUsers = users.map(user => {
    user match
      case user: Long => Some(user)
      case user: Option[Long] => user
  }).filter(_.isDefined)
  .map(user => {
    user.get
  })
  
  println(cleanUsers)
  println(cleanUsers.length)
  
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bwCYFf7YQt6gbxbjdbaIqA

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the simplest solution:

```
val users: Seq[Long] = Seq(x) ++ y.toSeq ++ z.toSeq
```

`toSeq` will turn `None` into `Nil` and `Some(x)` into `List(x)`, and then you can just concatenate the lists.

Answer (score 0):

`appended(value)` returns  `a new sequence consisting of all elements of this sequence followed by value.` . It doesnt change in-place.

If you want to keep the way your code looks like, you can do

```
    var users: Seq[Long] = Seq(x) // change val to var

    if (y.isDefined) users = users.appended(y.get)
    if (z.isDefined) users = users.appended(z.get)
```

Note:
This

```
    if (y.isDefined) users = users.appended(y.get)
    if (z.isDefined) users = users.appended(z.get)
```

could be changed to

```
    y.foreach(users :+= _)
    z.foreach(users :+= _)
```

Comment: If going the imperative route it would have been better to use `y.foreach(users :+= _)` - Instead of checking if the option is defined.

Comment: This is really not making good using of the `Option` class.

Comment: Agree. But I just wanted to highlight that the appended is not in-place and that's why `users` is not updated (too long to be in a comment)

Comment: @ccheneson I appreciate this answer, it really shows the difference between `var` and `val` and how to update the immutable `Seq`. Thanks!

Comment: I also didn't realize you could call `.get` on a option like this 

Comment: You can use `get`, but you shouldn't because in the general case it is not safe. Use `getOrElse` or a `match` or some other way of processing the value in an `Option`.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,
I am pretty late to the party, but just wanted to share an idea.  I am also learning how to use scala....

*If* your data is such that the number may-or-may-not exist (maybe there are some nulls in your datastream), you might acknowledge this in your model and make user a `Seq[Option[Long]]`.  This would signal to anybody looking at your code that they may expect some of the entries in the list could be null/empty.

You can then take advantage of the map/flatMap goodness of monads to easily sequence this data without the worry of "nulls".

I realize this is a rather academic comment; I've been reading a ton of good scala papers lately.

Comment: `Long` being value type and `Null` being reference type, is this even possible?

Comment: I was thinking of an example where some of the input data was missing.  Let's say we are reading a line of csv longs from some stream.  The stream contains:
123,456,,789. <- 3rd value is missing!

If I model my data like this:
@ val inputData: Seq[Option[Long]] = Seq(Some(123), Some(456), None, Some(789))
inputData: Seq[Option[Long]] = List(Some(value = 123L), Some(value = 456L), None, Some(value = 789L))

Then,
@ inputData.flatMap {
    case value @ Some(v)  => value
    case None => None
  }
res50: Seq[Long] = List(123L, 456L, 789L)

This allowed me to skip missing values.